# how do you put a datepicker into a django app?

Tags: python, django, widget, datepicker

I'd like to put a datepicker type of widget into my Django app so that users don't have to try and use a textbox to enter a date and a time.  I've found some references to widgets and forms but can't find anything about how to put them into a page on my Django site.  Any guidance on how to use these features to meet this end would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I realize you posted this some time ago, but did you ever get this working? Have you tried [my datepicker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker)?

Comment: @Eonasdan Hi, would you mind to go into detail on how to add this into a django project? I mean, I already have added the `.js` and `.css` files into my header but I need it to work with my fields in `models.py` (which uses `DateTimeField` field) and show them in my `views.py`. Date Time Picker already shows if I add the `input` into my HTML template but thats not what I want. Would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker does [not work in Bootstrap 3.0](https://github.com/tarruda/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/231) (is not mantained anymore). I use [this one](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker), and it solves my problem. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a javascript date/time picker that populates a text field with the date/time.

Here is an example: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

Comment: I copied over the code in the example you gave me the little calendar button that should be on the side isn't appearing.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You should add the javascipt and css files: http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/dist/bootstrap-datetimepicker-0.0.11.zip

Comment: And jquery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: after downloading those js and css files, how do I make use of them?

Comment: You can put them in your HTML like so: `<script src="myscripts.js"></script>` and `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_file.css">`

Comment: Still no button after adding those files in and putting in the jQuery import suggested.

Comment: That one is a bit complicated. This is a date time picker that is simpler to implement: http://www.rainforestnet.com/datetimepicker/datetimepicker-tutorial.htm

Comment: That one doesn't give me a button either.